# Eclipse export runnable jar - exclude javadoc and sources

Tags: eclipse, executable-jar

I'm exporting my swing application as a runnable jar file. So far so good. I noticed that in every export all the unit-tests, sources and javadoc for each library are included. which means a big overhead for the application. 
How can I define only to export the used class files, and only the core-libraries without javadoc?

This application run not with maven.

thanks

//edit, some pictures:
As example guava, who is saved in 3 jars ( code, sources, javadoc) in my lib folder.

[image: lib folder]

My build path settings where i define the sources and javadoc
[image: buildpath settings]

and the with 7-zip opened jar, where sources and javadocs are included, but **shouldn't** be.
[image: jar]

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: Nope, switched to maven ;)

Answer (score 2):

Right-click on the project,choose Properties > Java Build path > Order and Export,or you can pick what you want to export from the `export wizard`.

//EDIT:
Choose a lighter jar,e.g,you can download Guava from 
http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/google/guava/guava/14.0.1/guava-14.0.1.jar instead of your jar which contains source and doc file.That's the reason that makes your project so large.

Comment: as my libraries are with javadoc and sources, i see no possiblity to exclude jdoc and sources..

Comment: I guess that you downloaded a jar file with name like `xxx-version-all.jar`?Basically this kind of jar file contains javadoc,demos,test cases and source code package in one.If so,choose a lighter one.

Comment: i edited my question, so may it's clearer whats the problem, thank you

Comment: My char does _not_ contain the sources, they are in a other jar, totally 3, is there no possibility to tell eclipse to only export the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Eclipse export to create a runnable jar, but you want to control which files to include and which files to exclude, follow the following steps:

1. File > Export > Runnable JAR file > Next
2. Configure export options
3. Check the "Save as ANT script" option > Finish
4. Edit the ANT script to include/exclude files
5. Right click on the ANT script > Run As > Ant Build

That's it!